# Clarification on locally finite graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I'm looking for some clarification regarding infinite graphs.

Assuming a graph could be undirected or directed, the concept
of locally finite seems not clear to me. It was told to me that
a graph is *locally finite* if the valency for every node in the graph is
a finite set.

Consider the following two graphs:

[image]

The graph in a) is a directed locally finite graph. While the graph in b)
is a undirected graph which it's not locally finite, the center of this star graph has infinite valency.

Is the definition of locally finiteness still valid as I wrote above? even
when the graph is directed? Certainly the graph in a) is an infinite graph.
In other words, an infinite graphs could be a locally finite graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the definitions rather clear:

- A *locally finite graph* is a graph in which the degree of each vertex is finite.
- A *locally finite digraph* is a digraph in which the indegree **and** the outdegree of each vertex is finite.

In your examples, graph $b$ is **not** locally finite because it has a vertex with infinite degree (this is what I assumed you meant by your drawing), while digraph $a$ is **not** locally finite because it has a vertex with infinite indegree.

Every digraph $D$ which is an orientation of a graph $G$ not locally finite, will be a digraph not locally finite : Take the vertex $v\in V(G)$ with infinite degree, and look at the orientation of it edges in $D$. In $D$, either its indegree or its outdegree must be infinite, therefore the digraph is not locally finite.

Comment: Thank you, now I see.